# Prove that that the function $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=ye^x+xz^2$ is differentiable at the point (0,-4,2) using definition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Prove that that the function $f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=ye^x+xz^2$ is differentiable at the point $\vec a=\langle 0,-4,2\rangle$ using definition.

My attempt:- Let $\vec{h}=\langle h_1,h_2,h_3\rangle.$ Then we need to prove

$$\lim_{\vec{h}\to \vec 0}\frac{f(\vec a+\vec{h})-f(\vec a)-f_x(\vec a)h_1-f_y(\vec a)h_2-f_z(\vec a)h_3}{||\vec h||}=0.$$
Consider the LHS
$$\lim_{\vec{h}\to \vec 0}\frac{f(\vec a+\vec{h})-f(\vec a)-f_x(\vec a)h_1-f_y(\vec a)h_2-f_z(\vec a)h_3}{||\vec h||}=\\\lim_{\vec{h}\to \vec 0}\frac{(-4+h_2)e^{h_1}+h_1(2+h_3)^2+4-h_2}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2+h_3^2}}$$

I can use $(-4+h_2)\leq h_2$. I don't know how to proceed after that. I used spherical coordinated. I used all the possibilities available for me. Could you help me?

Comment: Think about grouping terms so that you can see explicitly why the numerator goes to $0$. And remember it’s about absolute values, so $|-4+h_2|\le |h_2|$ is very false.

Comment: okay. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spherical coordinates will help you to notice that any term containing $h_1^{p_1}h_2^{p_2}h_3^{p_3}/||\vec h||$ with $p_1+p_2+p_3>1$ will tend to $0$ in the limit $\vec h\to\vec 0$. How is this important? It means that you can skip all higher order terms, like $h_i^2$ or $h_ih_j$.
$$f(\vec a+\vec h)-f(\vec a)=(-4+h_2)e^{h_1}+h_1(2+h_3)^2+4$$
In the second term one will keep $4h_1$ and disregard higher powers. Similarly, in the first term, once you write $$e^{h_1}=1+h_1+\cal O(h_1^2)$$
Then
$$f(\vec a+\vec h)-f(\vec a)=-4+h_2-4h_1+4h_1+4+\cal O(h^2)=h_2+\cal O(h^2)$$
In order that the limit is $0$, you get $f_x=0$, $f_y=1$, $f_z=0$